# Cancel running system() thread on macOS

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macos

I have a simple threaded function that plays audio in the background that I'd like to kill. It looks like this:

```c
void
*music_thread(void *vargp)
{
    t_lst   *cl;

    cl = (t_lst *)vargp;
    cl->isoldmus = 1;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    system("aplay -f cd -t wav -q mymusic.wav");
    return (NULL);
}
```

I can cancel it with ease on Linux with:

```c
pthread_cancel(cl->tid);
pthread_join(cl->tid, NULL);
```

However with the same code compiled on macOS the thread does not get canceled and the program is waiting for the music to be over to continue. The only difference is the `system()` command being:

```c
system("afplay --volume 0.2 mymusic.wav");
```

I could use another `system()` to `pkill` the runing `afplay` process but I'd like to avoid that if I could. `pthread_kill()` did not work either. How can I cancel that on macOS?
I compile with clang 10 on macOS Mojave and clang 9.0.1 on Gentoo Linux 4.19.97.

Comment: I want to understand something, your call to the function `system` is not blocking? after the start of `afplay` command, the thread continues its execution and ends right?

Comment: Try pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL).   Macos defaults to DEFERRED.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a better way to solve your problem. If all your music thread does is to call `system` and wait for it to finish, it would be better to drop the thread  and call `afplay` with `fork`/`exec`. You can then stop `afplay` by sending it `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`. Even if you need the thread, using `fork`/`exec` is preferable to using `system`. The child  process may then run in parallel, and you have a `pid` you may manipulate.

Comment: The thread is indeed blocked by `system` until `afplay` finishes. I will try with `fork`/`execve` as it seems to be a better choice overhaul for shell commands, thank you.